# Guardar el valor de dos inputs

Tags: laravel

Hola estoy almacenando datos con Laravel, pero quiero guardar dos campos del formulario en la misma columna de la base de datos.

```
$presupuesto->persona = $request->input('persona');
```

Además de guardar el

```
input('persona')
```

quiero guardar tambien el

```
input apellidos.
```

Comment: Porque se construyo así en su momento, a pesar de ser una mala idea quiero saber si es posible hacerlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba de esta forma:

Declaramos una variable que será la que almacene el nombre completo que es el que pretendemos almacenar:

```
$nombreCompleto = $request->nombre." ".$request->apellidos;
```

Lo anterior generará que almacenemos un solo valor en dicha variable, el cual podremos usar posteriormente para almacenar:

```
$presupuesto->persona = $nombreCompleto;
```

Comment: Me trae solo el apellido @BetaM

Comment: No he dicho nada, hay que cambiar `nombre` por `persona` ya que lo tengo así en la bd, gracias!